# Continous auth on Google Calendar API

Tags: php, google-api, google-api-client

I'm trying to make some read calls to my own calendar via PHP so I can let it return json to my frontend.

I've read up on the subject on https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/php/auth/web-app and used their "Complete example" as a basis.

This works perfectly well. You call the index.php, the session isn't found so it redirects you, gets you a key you can put in your url by `?code=[code]` etc. It sets the sessions and **I get results!**

BUT. I don't want to do this every time I restart my browser but I want it to auto-validate itself.

Now I know there's a refresh token of some sorts as found in the "Getting started" guide found here: https://developers.google.com/google-apps/tasks/quickstart/php#further_reading

But this is only a terminal thing and I have no clue whatsoever how I can integrate this in the complete example code.

So in short: How can I do a one-time-auth in my browser so it will run 'indefinitely' every time I boot up my computer/browser?

*Here's my code I shamelessly stole from the link above:*

**index:**

```
require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

session_start();
define('APPLICATION_NAME', 'GoogasdAPI PHP Quickstart');
define('CREDENTIALS_PATH', '~/.credentials/calendar-php.json');
define('CLIENT_SECRET_PATH', __DIR__ . '/client_secret.json');
define('SCOPES', implode(' ', array(
    Google_Service_Calendar::CALENDAR_READONLY)
));

$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setAuthConfig(CLIENT_SECRET_PATH);
$client->setScopes(SCOPES);

if (isset($_SESSION['access_token']) && $_SESSION['access_token']) {
    $client->setAccessToken($_SESSION['access_token']);

    $service = new Google_Service_Calendar($client);
    $items = getCalendarResults(10, array('adgg@gmail.com', 'asd@gmail.com'));

    echo json_encode($items);
} else {
    $redirect_uri = 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/proberen/ja/oauth2callback.php';
    header('Location: ' . filter_var($redirect_uri, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));
}
```

And **oauth2callback.php**:

```
require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

session_start();
define('APPLICATION_NAME', 'Google Calendar API PHP Quickstart');
define('CREDENTIALS_PATH', '~/.credentials/calendar-php-quickstart.json');
define('CLIENT_SECRET_PATH', __DIR__ . '/client_secret.json');
define('SCOPES', implode(' ', array(
  Google_Service_Calendar::CALENDAR_READONLY)
));

$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setAuthConfig(CLIENT_SECRET_PATH);
$client->setScopes(SCOPES);

if (! isset($_GET['code'])) {
  $auth_url = $client->createAuthUrl();
  header('Location: ' . filter_var($auth_url, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));
} else {
  $client->authenticate($_GET['code']);
  $_SESSION['access_token'] = $client->getAccessToken();
  $redirect_uri = 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/proberen/ja/';
  header('Location: ' . filter_var($redirect_uri, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));
}
```

Comment: Please check $_SESSION['access_token'] after authorization in index file

Comment: But that's the point. I DON'T want it based on a session. If I close the browser, the session is gone.

Comment: you can store access_token into database as well

Comment: The access token is only valid for one hour....

Comment: check this may be useful for your requirement http://www.daimto.com/google-calendar-api-with-php-service-account/